# JAVA - The Main Window doesn't appear i have to left click on the mainWindow.java and click run to see it

Tags: java, window

i'm making a program for my job, but when i click run to the already builded program nothing seems to happen, but when i go to the package VIEW , and left click the jFrame mainWindow.java and click run, appears the window and i can actually use the entire functions of the program

my question is, how can i make the mainWindow appear with just running the builded program ??????????

Im using Netbeans as IDE and Java as the programming language

sorry for my english it's not very good

Comment: Netbeans is using a main class that isn't your frame. Go into the project properties and change the main class. Also, make sure the project is setup as the "main" project

Comment: Thank you very much !!! i changed the main class and it worked perfectly, Thanks again! :D